# How to insert records in table that references the same table twice in ADF programmatically?

Tags: java, oracle12c, oracle-adf

I have a hierarchy that I want to populate using Oracle ADF which is as follows:

> Strategy table : strgID, strgName
>
> Objective table : objvID, objvName, strgID (Foreign Key)
>
> Objectives_rel table : parentObjvID (Foreign Key), childObjvID (Foreign Key)

The idea is that each strategy has some objectives, and each objective is either a level 1 objective, so it has no parent, or a level > 1, which means it has a parent objective. This parent child relationship is declared in the Objectives_rel table, where a record in this table symbolizes a parent-child relationship.

**What I am trying to do is**, using a Json object that shows this hierarchy of Strategy and objectives, to populate the three tables (Strategy, Objective, Objective_rel) programmatically.

I have successfully managed to insert the records if the Json has a strategy and level 1 objectives only, but I cannot model the relations table properly.

Please note that I need to stick to the current tables hierarchy, as I am not the Database owner.

Edit:

Here is the code I use to insert strategy and level 1 objectives

```
    AppModuleImpl am = null;
    try {
        am = (AppModuleImpl) Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(AM_DEF_NAME, AM_CONFIG_NAME);


        BpmStrgViewImpl strgView = am.getBpmStrgView1();
            String jsonString =
            "{\"name\":\"strg 1\",\"level\":0,\"objectives\":[{\"name\":\"objv 1\", \"level\": 1, \"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 3\", \"level\": 2, \"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 7\", \"level\": 3, \"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 13\", \"level\": 4, \"children\":null},{\"name\":\"objv 14\", \"level\": 4, \"children\":null}]},{\"name\":\"objv 8\", \"level\": 3, \"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 15\", \"level\": 4, \"children\":null}]}]},{\"name\":\"objv 4\", \"level\": 2, \"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 9\", \"level\": 3, \"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 16\", \"level\": 4, \"children\":null}]},{\"name\":\"objv 10\", \"level\": 3, \"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 17\", \"level\": 4, \"children\":null}]}]}]},{\"name\":\"objv 2\", \"level\": 1, \"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 5\", \"level\": 2,\"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 11\", \"level\": 3, \"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 18\", \"level\": 4, \"children\":null}]}]},{\"name\":\"objv 6\", \"level\": 2,\"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 12\", \"level\": 3, \"children\":[{\"name\":\"objv 19\", \"level\": 4, \"children\":null}]}]}]}]}";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        traverseStrategy(json, strgView);

        am.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    public static void traverseStrategy(JSONObject strategy, BpmStrgViewImpl strgView){

    BpmStrgViewRowImpl row = (BpmStrgViewRowImpl)strgView.createRow();

    row.setAttribute("ReqId", "12343");
    row.setAttribute("StrgCd", "OBJ__CD999");
    row.setAttribute("StrgNameAr", strategy.get("name"));

    strgView.insertRow(row);

    if(strategy.has("objectives")){
        JSONArray objectives = (JSONArray) strategy.get("objectives");

        // Loop over level 1 objectives
        for (int i = 0; i < objectives.length(); i++) {
            traverseObjectivesLevelOne((JSONObject) objectives.get(i), row.getBpmObjvView());
        }
    }
}

public static void traverseObjectivesLevelOne(JSONObject objective, RowIterator objvView){
    BpmObjvViewRowImpl row = (BpmObjvViewRowImpl)objvView.createRow();

    row.setAttribute("ReqId", "12343");
    row.setAttribute("ObjvCd", "OBJ__CD332");
    row.setAttribute("ObjvLvl", objective.get("level"));
    row.setAttribute("ObjvNameAr", objective.get("name"));

    objvView.insertRow(row);

}
```